# Should I return a 404 for a has_one resource that doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Let's say I have an entity with a "has one" relationship to another entity. For a contrived example, say we have users, and they may or may not have a single car.

```rb
class Driver < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :car, optional: true
end
```

I then visit

```
/drivers/1/car
```

If the driver doesn't have a car, should it `404` or return `null` from a REST / Rails design perspective?

Comment: *shrug* The issue is a 404 won't indicate which resource doesn't exist. Personally I'd defer to "cars" and return a collection of zero or one. Ultimately it's down to opinion.

Comment: it depends on what you app needs to do :)